# Why is enum data type always declared out of main() in c?

Tags: c, enums, scope, declaration

why is enum data type declared out of the main() function?
what happens if we declare enum data type within the main()?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-enum-c/

Comment: The same reason you usually declare `struct` types outside of functions.

Comment: Yeah - they usually need more scope than main.

Comment: Usually because you have a program that is bigger than single function, and you want to use the `enum` in several different functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary that an enumeration should have a file scope. An enumeration can be declared in a block scope.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum E1 { N = 10 };

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N];

    enum E1 { N = 2 * N };

    int b[N];

    printf( "sizeof( a[] ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
    printf( "sizeof( b[] ) = %zu\n", sizeof( b ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( a[] ) = 40
sizeof( b[] ) = 80
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 7 Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just
>   after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
>   tag. **Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>   appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list.** Any
>   other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of
>   its declarator.

Usually enumerations are declared outside a function when they need a file scope that is when the same enumeration is used in several functions for example in a  parameter declaration list.